# How to switch through tabs programmatically in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Only one tab is visible at a time. The user selects the one using mouse/keyboard.
Suppose, there are three tabs on TabPane and there is a button on first. When user press the button, I want the second tab to be opened.
Then there must be some code to switch to second Tab that in bound to the button.

Is it possible programmatically?
If so, how?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(index);
```

or

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(someTab);
```

or

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
```

[Or...](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SingleSelectionModel.html)